# How to count occurrences of records in nested array field

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

Here is my data

```
[
  { // room data
    _id: '20ae0225-512a-405b-8b9f-d6ffdca6634c',
    games: [
      {
        _id: 'cb01da11-5809-43e6-b02e-e878b38f4e11',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: 'ef0d7656-38a1-4c82-982b-b4beb3941e07',
            user_name: 'Andrew'
          },
          {
            user_id: 'a13de96d-e137-41d8-bd5c-083d9dbc00d7',
            user_name: 'Jack'
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: '9b03d0ef-178e-49d1-8b86-6b63c1957d6f',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: 'ef0d7656-38a1-4c82-982b-b4beb3941e07',
            user_name: 'Andrew'
          },
          {
            user_id: '67acb8b7-1670-4c07-979a-8a6e481bfd95',
            user_name: 'Thomas'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: '733a30d5-a6c1-4ce2-a33b-c8dbf61f2a2e',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: 'a13de96d-e137-41d8-bd5c-083d9dbc00d7',
            user_name: 'Jack'
          },
          {
            user_id: '67acb8b7-1670-4c07-979a-8a6e481bfd95',
            user_name: 'Thomas'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  { // room data
    _id: '20ae0225-512a-405b-8b9f-d6ffdca6634c',
    games: [
      {
        _id: 'cb01da11-5809-43e6-b02e-e878b38f4e11',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: '67acb8b7-1670-4c07-979a-8a6e481bfd95',
            user_name: 'Thomas'
          },
          {
            user_id: 'a13de96d-e137-41d8-bd5c-083d9dbc00d7',
            user_name: 'Jack'
          },
          
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: '9b03d0ef-178e-49d1-8b86-6b63c1957d6f',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: 'ef0d7656-38a1-4c82-982b-b4beb3941e07',
            user_name: 'Andrew'
          },
          {
            user_id: '67acb8b7-1670-4c07-979a-8a6e481bfd95',
            user_name: 'Thomas'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        _id: '733a30d5-a6c1-4ce2-a33b-c8dbf61f2a2e',
        players: [
          {
            user_id: 'a13de96d-e137-41d8-bd5c-083d9dbc00d7',
            user_name: 'Jack'
          },
          {
            user_id: '67acb8b7-1670-4c07-979a-8a6e481bfd95',
            user_name: 'Thomas'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

i want to count the total number of occurrences of a player appearing in the game array by `user_name` or `_id`
Example: In first room, player `Andrew` joined 2 game. In second room, player `Andrew` joined 1 game. The result of the desired query is 3.

Please help me, I can't think of a suitable query for this problem. I don't use Mongoose, I use pure query.

Thank everyone.

Comment: What did you try ? What is the problem in your query? Try to post specific question what you are struggling with rather asking for answer for whole problem. You can have a look at [the code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct). 

For you question, you can find few examples here for complex document query https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [aggregation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/aggregation/) operations.

```
db.collection.aggregate({
  $unwind: "$games"
},
{
  $unwind: "$games.players"
},
{
  $group: {
    _id: "$games.players.user_name",
    count: {
      $sum: 1
    }
  }
})
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/5nD_vlz0CEb

Comment: Thank for support me, but i get a message errors when use your query: ```  Method "collection.aggregate()" accepts at most two arguments```, so what happend ?

Comment: @NguyenKhaNam, Have you seen the result on mongoplayground ? How do you test it? can you share more info.